# How to create labeled ouputSet with rapidminer?

Tags: java, rapidminer

I'm finishing the implementation of a new data mining technique in our research.

I want to profit by the defined measures and performance operators included in rapidminer, so I need to deliver a labeled data set to the performance operator.

Can anyone help me find how to create a labeled data set? (I have the label and the prediction, and my problem is how to create the output data table in the form of a labeled set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RapidMiner distinguishes between regular and special attributes. If you already have an example set with prediction and label attribute you have to change the role of these. But typically this roles are set when you import your data and the learning of the model.

You have to do this, because the performance operators expects two special attributes with the role 'label' and 'prediction'. Therefore, insert the "Set Role" operator before the performance operator and select the attribute name (use 'set additional roles' for more than one attribute) and the target role accordingly.